# Syntax error on shell script calling a sql script

Tags: sql, unix, oracle10g

I am trying to execute the following command at shell prompt:

```
nohup sqlplus  DB_ID/DB_PWD@DOMAIN @main.sql 490 >> result.out 2>>&1 &
```

main.sql is a sql script that accepts `490` as argument.
I get error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&'
```

What is wrong with the syntax?

Comment: whats the last & for? Was there a mistake while copy pasting it?

Comment: I got the syntax here:http://www.mail-archive.com/oracle-l@fatcity.com/msg35217.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax error comes from your redirection of STDERR to STDOUT. The required (and only valid) syntax is `2>&1`. It still does what you expect from it. The `>>` you do in the STDOUT redirection only helps for actual files and prevents the file data to be erased. For pipe redirection, this is not required and not even allowed syntax-wise.

The final correct syntax is

```
nohup sqlplus  DB_ID/DB_PWD@DOMAIN @main.sql 490 >> result.out 2>&1 &
```